# theano : undefined variable in class

Tags: python, class, undefined, theano

minimalist code:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np
from numpy import dtype

class logistic_regression(object):
# constructor
    def __init__(self,input,n_in,n_out):
    # initialise parameters
       self.W=theano.shared(value=np.zeros((n_in,n_out),dtype=theano.config.floatX),name='W',borrow=True)
    self.b=theano.shared(value=np.zeros((n_out,),dtype=theano.config.floatX),name='b',borrow=True)
    self.p_y_given_x=self.calculate_probability()
    self.neg_log_likelihood=self.calculate_neg_log_likelihood(y)
def calculate_probability(self):
    p_y_given_x=T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(input,self.W)+self.b)
    return p_y_given_x
def calculate_neg_log_likelihood(self,y):
    neg_log_likelihood=T.mean(T.log(self.p_y_given_x)[T.arange(y.shape[0]),y])
    return neg_log_likelihood
```

In the line:

```
self.neg_log_likelihood=self.calculate_neg_log_likelihood(y)
```

I get an error in eclipse:

> "undefined variable y"

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are passing a variable `y`, which isn't defined anywhere.
Eclipse is looking for a definition of a variable y, for example, `y=10`, in the scope of the constructor and then in the global scope.
Since it can not find it, it warns you.

Did you possibly meant to pass `p_y_given_x` variable?

Comment: the constructor of the class needs y as an input. once i added y as a n input the problem was resolved. now def __init__(self,input,n_in,n_out) reads as def __init__(self,input,y,n_in,n_out)